# Div are not showing up in right size for responsive webpage

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I need to design follow page with responsive design.

I managed to make it work but the line i have to add at top of each row is creating problem, it breaks the design and Box container doesn't show up of same size.

I tried set up fiddle example but design breaks on this for some reason

Fiddle Update: http://jsfiddle.net/uNjLu/5/

I need to show my page as show in the image below, How can i properly achieve this with responsive feature.

[image]

```
  <div class="large-12 content">
        <div class="cover-wrapper">
            <div class="cover-inner">
                <div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/243x324&text=[img 1]">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cover-wrapper">
            <div class="cover-inner">
                <div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/243x324&text=[img 2]">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cover-wrapper">
            <div class="cover-inner">
                <div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/243x324&text=[img 3]">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cover-wrapper">
            <div class="cover-inner">
                <div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/243x324&text=[img 4]">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: the CSS is very important to your question - try to add the relevant parts to your question.

Comment: I hate reinventing the wheel, http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: I am using foundation, How can this be done with foundation?

Comment: Updated my fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/uNjLu/5/

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker you gave a layout in the question.is that for large screens?? medium screens ?or for small screens? that design breaks because you have only large columns-they stack for medium and small screens.Try with small-12 columns it wont break. the classes depends on the layout you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Sudheer, This is screen for 768pixels & above. for 360pixels - 640pxels i will use two images in row and i image for anything less than 360pxels screen.

Comment: @Sudheer, I wanted to resolve issue div size issue first then work on the other screen. for now i am stuck with this, as i tried different thing but get stuck for one or the other issue. Problem is because of teh Line that i have to keep on top of each row and line & image start & end point need to be aligned with the Div

Answer (score 0):

You have many custom widths set on divs. these custom classes are overriding foundation classes.

If you want to use foundation classes here is a blue print of the way to do it..use `small-centered` and `medium-centered` classes to center them on respective screens

```css
img{
    margin:20px auto;   
}
.header{
        background-color:#7A1F13;
}
.slideshow{
    background-color:#7A1F13;
    height:200px;
}

.footer{
        background-color:#7A1F13;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/5.4.3/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!--header area-->
<div class="row header "> 
<h1 class="large-12  text-center">Header</h1>   
</div>
<div class="row  slideshow"> 
<h1 class="large-12  text-center">slideshow</h1>   
</div>
<!--header end-->
<!--Content area-->
<div class="large-12 content">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-3 columns">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/243x324&text=[img 1]">
            </div>
                <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-3 columns">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/243x324&text=[img 1]">
            </div>
                    <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-3 columns">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/243x324&text=[img 1]">
            </div>
                        <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-3 columns">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/243x324&text=[img 1]">
            </div>
    </div> 
                        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-3 columns">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/243x324&text=[img 1]">
            </div>
                <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-3 columns">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/243x324&text=[img 1]">
            </div>
                    <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-3 columns">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/243x324&text=[img 1]">
            </div>
                        <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-3 columns">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/243x324&text=[img 1]">
            </div>
    </div> 
                        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-3 columns">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/243x324&text=[img 1]">
            </div>
                <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-3 columns">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/243x324&text=[img 1]">
            </div>
                    <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-3 columns">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/243x324&text=[img 1]">
            </div>
                        <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-3 columns">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/243x324&text=[img 1]">
            </div>
    </div> 
</div>
<!--content end-->
<!--footer area-->
 <div class="row footer"><h1 class="large-12 columns text-center ">Footer Section</h1></div>
<!--footer end-->
</div>
```

Have a row class and nest them according to your needs.- `small-12 medium-6 large-3 columns`.

If `768px, 640px and 340px` are your breakpoints then you have change the media-queries.
you can do this by the following two methods.

`1) use sass files of foundation and change breakpoints
 2) change all the media-queries in css manually`

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/uNjLu/12/).

[fullscreen view](http://jsfiddle.net/uNjLu/12/embedded/result/)

Comment: My main question remain answer. How will you add line before each row lets us same for large, medium & small screen... That part i am facing difficulty with not the screen size i can manage that...